# Evolution of Interior Life

Tags: biology, fauna

"Interior Life? What's that?" Quite simply, it is life that lives *inside* something else. As far as I know, interior life is limited to microrganisms (bacteria like *E. coli*) or parasites (tapeworms, *Toxoplasma*, and so forth), and I have to wonder why.

Mucus inside the stomach (lining the stomach walls) prevents the acid there from eating its way out to the other organs, right? And there *are* species, like parrotfish, clownfish, and eels, that coat themselves in mucus for protection. Natural selection favors traits that enable greater survival, so why is it we don't have a fish that evolved to survive inside another being's stomach?

Coated in a layer of protective mucus, it'd be protected from predators (because what kind of predator would look *there* for food?) and have a free source of food that's already chewed and everything! Seriously, it'd just have to mutate so it produced stomach-wall-grade mucus from its skin, and if the aforesaid clownfish are any indication, it can happen. In fact, this thing might *be* a clownfish whose ancestors survived being eaten by their anemone!

Considering that species of early fish came out of the water and evolved into terrestrial organisms, and that air is trapped inside stomachs over time, air-breathing interior life may also be possible, though extremely unlikely. Extremophiles, like the bacteria that live in Yellowstone's geysers, hydrothermal tube worms, and the orange cave crocs, make it clear that this shouldn't be just a faint possibility.

So, in sum, my question is simple: **How Would Interior Life Come To Pass?**

**Criteria for Best Answer:**

1. The best answer will explain how interior life-specifically, complex organisms of higher orders than Annelida, like a fish or squid, or perhaps even some type or equivalent of hominid-could come into being, or **how and in what conditions complex life could develop to live inside another organism's stomach or digestive tract.** This organism may technically be parasitic, however if it is more complex than the above examples, it counts for this question.
2. While it certainly isn't necessary, I'd greatly appreciate it if answers first explain *why* life that lives inside other life is apparently relatively simple and limited in variety to microscopic organisms. A good example of what I'd be looking for would be cave fauna (like cave crickets), but adapted to the conditions of a stomach in particular, like acid, potentially low air, and so forth.

Comment: If the organism relies on a "free source of food", it will be considered an endoparasite by definition.

Comment: @MikeSerfas: that doesn't matter, I specified a "complex organism" not "non-parasite." Edited to clarify.

Comment: Or symbiotic as in endobacteria of ruminants (or us) and mitochondria. Ahhh, complex, there's a thing.

Comment: Well, it's not free if you pay for it. ;)

Comment: (a) Human babies live 9 months as "interior life." African elephants pregnancies last nearly two years. Bacteria lives inside all biological creatures throughout that creature's life. Can you be (a lot) more specific about what you're looking for? (b) This feels like an increasingly popular off-topic type of question that asks, "how can X evolve in real life?" We're supposed to be dealing with your fictional world. Are you seeking a rationalization for how "interior life" could exist? If so, then you're looking for what rules must exist, right?

Comment: @JBH: Thanks JBH for your comment, I will try to clarify as best I can. No, human babies during development do *not* count as interior life, specifically because they *don't* live inside another creature's stomach or digestive tract. I *am,* however, looking for an explanation of how a creature, as complex as a fish or even a hominid, could develop to fulfill the above condition.

Comment: @JBH: As for what rules must exist, I believe that's covered by "how and in what conditions complex life could develop to live inside another organism's stomach or digestive tract." If you have suggestions for how I can improve the question, though, I'm all ears.

Comment: google tongue-eating louse which eats then replaces the tongues of fish. Your big limitation in the stomach is access to oxygen, which is almost non-existent in the stomach, plus you mucus covered gills won't function.  so either your gills get digested or you are small enough to not need gills like tape worms. The stomach evolved to be as inhospitable to life as possible.

Comment: you can also google stomach worms. which is basically what you want.

Comment: The assumption underlying criterium (2) is not accurate. It depends on size. Life inside other life is not rare at all. Macroscopic life (same order of size compared to the host) is rare.. because in non-symbiotic cases, it would be deadly for the host. But if you'd count fungi, bacteria and worms as "life" there are millions of species ! e.g. our human body contains an entire ecosystem of species, subject to natural selection (and therefore evolution)

Comment: @John: thank you for your comments, I think they have the makings of a great answer! I'm looking for larger forms of life, something like sea life _inside_ a creature, so perhaps said stomach worms could evolve into something like eels?

Comment: @Goodies: thank you for the enlightenment, I've added clarification to compensate.

Comment: Mostly the reason that fish can't live in the digestive tract of other larger organisms is the lack of oxygenated water. Even if they could evolve some other respiratory organ more suited to "Stomach Life", there's just no O2 to salvage in that environment. Otherwise, this isn't the worst premise I've heard of here. If you can come up with some explanation for that, I'd say it's a grade B+ science fiction concept, and I might even be undergrading you.

Comment: @JohnO: no _oxygen_, you say? What about carbon dioxide?

Comment: @Alendyias You won't get much of any gas exchange there, stomachs tend to contract to be only as large as they need to contain the food. The stomach acid itself is, volume-wise, quite minimal and I don't believe it to be enough to contain significant amounts even if those gases were solutes to the acid. You almost need some alien metabolism that does not require breathing at all, to make this work. Which is probably why the premise doesn't happen in nature. Hmm. Maybe some sort of tendril "snorkel" up through the esophagus to where it can suck in a breath. If it didn't choke the host, that is.

Answer (score 8):

### The ecstasy fish

Legends of the [candiru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candiru_(fish)) have stalked the nightmares of men from prehistoric times.  But as humans invaded their environment, the fish had to adapt and evolve.  That opportunity came, at last, when a raid on a Brazilian drug lab dumped genetically engineered yeast into a tributary of the Amazon.
With their skin flora supercharged with constructs producing potent enkephalin analogs, the once dreaded candiru became known as the very emissaries of pleasure.  Every moment of contact with the fish is ecstasy, even where its spines anchor it in place.  Biological fluids released in never-ending waves by its hosts permitted the fish to thrive and survive, while the host's respiration provided sufficient oxygen for the quiescent fish to survive.

From chance contactees to spiritual seekers, to urban adventurers and at last the cartel market, the fish spread rapidly.  Viewing them as a method of neutralizing enemy troops or unwanted lower class populations, government authorities looked on the fish with bemusement and a certain smug self-satisfaction.  But as the list of unauthorized genetic modifications grew, it was only a matter of time before the fish began to spread to unexpected places in the body ... and the world...

Answer (score 2):

*(I realize below example is morbid.. so @dog lovers please avoid reading below example, I'd like to explain how  a genetic change in an exoparasetic insect, followed by adaptation and natural selection - sometimes inadvertedly accellerated by humans - could yield an endoparasite, living inside the body, and not deadly at first)*

**The digging dog flea**

A behavioural change took place involving a common dog flea species, some 1200 years ago. As a result of a mutation, the flea developed the ability to survive with less oxigen, it can now extract all oxigen needed from blood. After being fertalized, a female flea can dig herself into the skin and reside under the skin, instead of being clamped on top of it, vulnerable for scratching and preditors. Eggs grow in the flea itself, like the Jigger flea does. Digging fleas need to make a cavity, which causes a painfull itch for the dog around its tail. When the eggs hatch, the female flea dies and the cavity would burst open, larvae emigrate with the dog's excrements. The excrements provide a place for coccoons and new fleas will infest other dogs.

The cavity is left to heal, the dog survives the parasite, which is going inside now.

Initially, digging variant did not replace the common dog flea. But for about 1000 years, there was peace: a fleas infested dogs, but nobody noticed some dog fleas actually *went through* dog skin and could escape hygiene measures ! Dogs experienced more itching, and while their owners started to take measures to help them get rid of fleas, the digging variant thrived: measures taken were the old, known measures against fleas,  many of the old dog flea species went extinct, the digging flea survived the measures.

The dogs survived too.. but in the 18th century, certain (expensive) dog breeds had a problem ! Because of the persistent scratching, the fur of the dogs looked bad. Dogs are selectively bred by humans for esthetic and commercial reasons.. to help "improve their dog race", humans now started to selectively breed the symptoms away: only dogs that did not scratch all the time could be sold for good money.

During 1000 years, the digging flea had only caused an itch. It lived beneath the skin, with no grave consequences for the dog. The dog could easily survive the flea development cycle.

But humans did (again) not realize the consequences of their action: fighting the scratching symptom, modifying their dogs, allowed the *deepest digging* fleas to survive. These fleas would penetrate deeper into the flesh.. not  causing itching and scratching. They survived.

After 1200 years and 3 evolutionary steps, 2 of which involved natural selection and adaptation, 21thC humans finally found out what had been going wrong. The eggs now hatched *inside* the animal. To prevent massive spread of the larvae, they could only cremate their dog.. in an attempt to extinguish the bugger..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flea

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_flea

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunga_penetrans

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trombicula

Comment: Interesting, so ectoparasites, like fleas, could become endoparasites and fulfill the criteria of this question! Very enlightening....

Comment: I found Trombicula the most frightening.. a little spider.. " After crawling onto their hosts, they inject digestive enzymes into the skin that break down skin cells"

Answer (score 1):

> (...) complex organisms of higher orders than Annelida, like a fish or squid, or perhaps even some type or equivalent of hominid-could come into being, or how and in what conditions complex life could develop to live inside another organism's stomach or digestive tract.

Sea cucumbers are often home to small fish, who enter the cucumber by an orifice that is not the mouth. Sometimes the fish will also eat the cucumber's innards, which is why Lady Evolution bestowed upon some cucumbers nature's greatest weapon for self defense: [**anal teeth**](https://www.karger.com/Article/Pdf/142845).

Most cucumbers are chill about fish though. I could leave a picture here of a pearlfish and a sea cucumber, but that is the kind of thing that once you see you can't unsee, so [I will just leave a link to an image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sea+cucumber+pearlfish&tbm=isch) which you can check if you want. The fish have their heads out, but they can go completely inside if they sense danger.

---

Also, [some shrimp live inside some sponges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus%27_flower_basket), but that is not as impressive as echinoderms with teeth in their assess.

---

Oh, and did you know that [some insects lay eggs inside human wounds](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/myiasis/faqs.html)? The larva develop under your skin.

Comment: So it does exist, it is plausible! Thank you for this knowledge!